# CSS3 Card Flip and Expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a collection of cards/divs within a container.  When a card/div is clicked, it should flip horizontally and expand to take up the entire space within the container (basically changing the size of the card/div to 100% x 100% when clicked).  I'm unsure if this is possible or not, as all of the examples that I've seen out there typically involve the card/div remaining the same size.

Here's the fiddle I tried working with, but I can't get the basic flipping functionality: https://jsfiddle.net/4dazznb5/

```js
$('.card').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('flipped');
  });
  return false;
});
```

```css
.cards {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  perspective: 800;
}

.cards .card {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
  z-index: 2;
}

.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
}

.flip .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  background: white;
}

.cards .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  
  position: relative;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 600px;">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face front">Card 1 Front</div>
      <div class="face back">Card 2 Back</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face front">Card 2 Front</div>
      <div class="face back">Card 2 Back</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="face front">Card 3 Front</div>
      <div class="face back">Card 3 Back</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want `.card` div full height when click?

Comment: @ketan: Ideally, when you click the div, it has a flip effect, and consumes the full height.  So, yes!

Comment: @Blockis there is a card flip I did for the track listings on this site: http://etonmessy.com/ I'm not sure if it will help you or not. But I thought I would also just give a heads up on animating to full width - css animating by anything other than transform/opacity does tend to be a little jerky. I'm not sure you'll get the effect you want with just transform: scale(); , but if not, you may want to give it some consideration.

Answer (score 5):

Since [Tambo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065597/tambo) backfaces were better (allowing html content), I made this mix with our answers (*tested with success on Mozilla and Chrome*):

```js
$('.card').click(function(){  
 
  if (!$(this).hasClass("flipped")) {
  $( ".face" ).addClass( 'off' );
  $( this ).children( ".face" ).removeClass( 'off' );
  $( this ).parent( ".cards" ).addClass( 'big' );
  $( this ).addClass('flipped');

  } else {
 
  $( ".face" ).removeClass( 'off' );
  $( ".cards" ).removeClass( 'big' );
  $( this ).removeClass('flipped'); 
}
  

});
```

```css
body {
height:100vh;
width:100vw;
margin:0px;
}

#container {
position: relative;
background: skyblue;
height:100%;
width:60%;
overflow: hidden;
margin:auto;
}

.off {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) !important;
  background: rgba(230, 230, 250, 0.0) !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 2s;
}

.cards {
  -webkit-perspective: 900px;
  -moz-perspective: 900px;
  perspective: 900px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 1s;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
 }
 
.cards .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.cards .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 1s;
}

.cards .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden ;
  backface-visibility: hidden ;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.cards .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  background: tomato;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cards .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  background: gold;
}

.cards .card .front,
.cards .card .back{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.big {
height:100%;
width:100%;
top: 0% !important;
margin-left: 0%;
margin-right: 0%;
z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=container>

<div class=cards style="top:0px"> 
<div class=card> 
   <div class="face front"> 
      Card 1 Front
    </div> 
    <div class="face back"> 
      Card 1 Back
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 

<div class=cards style="top:25%"> 
    <div class=card> 
    <div class="face front"> 
      Card 2 Front
    </div> 
    <div class="face back"> 
      Card 2 Back
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>

 <div class=cards style="top:50%"> 
   <div class=card> 
    <div class="face front"> 
      Card 3 Front
    </div> 
    <div class="face back"> 
      Card 3 Back
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>

<div class=cards style="top:75%">
   <div class=card> 
    <div class="face front"> 
      Card 4 Front
    </div> 
    <div class="face back"> 
      Card 4 Back
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `!important` to the new 'flipped' class attributes overwrites the old ones. The javascript line `$( ".item" ).not( this ).addClass( 'off' )` removes the other cards when one is selected. The `absolute` position let everything on its place. The active card have a higher z-index to ensures that other cards will not activate the 'mouseleave' trigger. **UPDATE:** finally working 100% on Mozilla and Chrome. *ps: a click opens the card and another click closes it.*

```js
$('.item').click(function(){  
 
  if (!$(this).hasClass("flipped")) {
  $( ".item" ).not( this ).addClass( 'off' );
  $( this ).addClass('flipped');

  } else {
 
  $( ".item" ).removeClass( 'off' );
  $( this ).removeClass('flipped'); 
}
  

});
```

```css
.off {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) !important;
  background: rgba(230, 230, 250, 0.0) !important;
}

.cards {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: lavender;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-perspective: 900px;
  perspective: 900px;
}

.flipped {
  top: 0% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 1s;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  z-index:100;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: tomato;
}

.flipped:after {
  content: 'More text on here.';
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  background: gold;
}

.card {
  height: 22%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;  
  cursor: pointer;  
  -webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 1s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: tomato;
}

.aaa {
top:0%;  
}

.bbb {
top:26%;  
}

.ccc {
top:52%;  
}

.ddd {
top:78%;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 600px;">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card item aaa">
      <div class="face front">Some text on here.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card item bbb">
      <div class="face front">Some text on here.</div>
    </div>
      <div class="card item ccc">
      <div class="face front">Some text on here.</div>
    </div>
      <div class="card item ddd">
      <div class="face front">Some text on here.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're really close!  The effect didn't seem to run too well in Chrome for me, is it missing some vendor-prefixes?  Also, is it possible to make it so when you click one card, it hides the other cards? (maybe via jQuery, .hide()?)

Comment: There's an issue that I'm trying to fix: to avoid a scroll bar, we must use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`; but with display:none when we click in a card that isnt the first, the card jumps (outside of the mouse cursor) to the top when the others disappear before to grow and it activates the trigger "mouseleave" so the animation stops. It works good in all cards if we change the "mouseleave" for another "click". The solution is probably to use visibility:hidden to the child < the current child and display:none to the child > the current child.

Comment: problem of the previous comment fixed with `position:absolute` on cards.

Comment: I just realized you dont need to remove the old class, just add !important on the new one (:

Comment: ps: mine, yours and Tambo's versions dont work in firefox! maybe you'll need to change "mouseleave" for "click" to be compatible in all browsers.

Comment: So I still see both lines of text in the initial front "side" of the divs, is this not compatible with Chrome?

Comment: I didnt get what you mean... screenshot?

Comment: oh now I got, it was supposed to be each inner div in a different side of the card (dont need screenshot)

Comment: Also, if I wanted to change how it flips back to the original content, would I be able to programmatically just change the .mouseleave(...) to .click(...)?

Comment: Just substitute it for 'Click' and it does works. But only works once! So I'm trying to identify why is it only working one time (and no more).

Comment: The problem is: 'mouseleave' works 100% on chrome and 50%on mozilla. 'click' (on this situation) works only on mozilla (and only once); 'mouseup' works only on mozilla aswell.. I didnt find anything that works on both.

Comment: Is it possible to have a "face back" div for each card, instead of setting the content in CSS?

Comment: yes there's an exemple of it on the Tambo's snippet (below here); I just made a quicker version since this isnt the question focus;

Comment: The current snippet works 100% good on chrome and 50% on firefox. Heres alternatives: [click version](https://jsfiddle.net/c25jb3x8/) works 100% good on firefox but 50% on chrome. [mouseup version](https://jsfiddle.net/edb9jdmj/) works 100% good on firefox but doesnt works on chrome.

Comment: Clicking on the flipped div doesn't flip it back :( (Chrome)

Comment: I did a [public question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493630/fail-hover-on-css-rotatex-at-firefox-fail-jquery-click-on-chrome); Probably someone will know how to fix this cross browsers issue.

Comment: I got zero answers on my public question. Anyway, I just found the problem was Chrome were ignore clicks on backface since its visibility was set to hidden. So I did remove it from "flipped" and its working 100% on both browsers now. I'm done here :)

Answer (score 0):

Just play with [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

```js
// Function to flip the card and expand the content 
function flipMe() {
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
  var card = this.querySelector('.card');
  card.classList.add('flipped');
  // this handler will be executed every time the cursor is moved off the card
  card.addEventListener("mouseout", function( event ) {   
    this.classList.remove('flipped');
  }, false);
}
// Define our variables
var cardWrapper = document.querySelector('.cardWrapper');
 

cardWrapper.addEventListener("click", flipMe, false);
```

```css
:root {
 background: #CAC8CC;
}
.cardWrapper {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  perspective: 800;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.cardWrapper .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  height: 100%;
}
.cardWrapper .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
.cardWrapper .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden ;
  backface-visibility: hidden ;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}
.cardWrapper .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
.cardWrapper .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  transform: rotatex(-180deg);
  background-color: #0095ff;
}
.cardWrapper .card .front,
.cardWrapper .card .back{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class=cardWrapper> 
  <div class=card> 
    <div class="face front"> 
      Card 1 Front
    </div> 
    <div class="face back"> 
      Card 1 Back
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Excuse-me, lady. I hope you don't mind I did mix your answer with mine to produce a 3rd improved answer.